# Tabulator - Pagination does not render new information after I add a row

Tags: pagination, render, updating

I have the pagination control displaying on the bottom of the data grid. If I add rows to the grid the pagination display does not update until I click on a page or prev/next/first/last button.

After a row is added a render event should be fired to the pagination control that should update the bar.  Is there a render call I can issue that will force a repaint of the paginator bar?

Thanks,

Mark